# Rotate image when insert in docs with apps script

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a document generator which is opening a docs template and replaces placeholders by images and text.
There is now one image which has to be rotated when it is replacing a placeholder. Due to the fact, that i want to automate everything, it is no option to rotate the image manually befor selecting.
Anyone knows a solution? I want to specify the rotation with the variables of the placeholder.

This is my function:

```
 `   for (var placeholder in placeholders) {
      const foundElement = body.findText(placeholder);
      if (foundElement) {
        var imageId = strukturSheet.getRange(placeholders[placeholder].cell).getValue();
    
        // Check if image-ID is empty
        if (imageId) {
          var imageFile = DriveApp.getFileById(imageId);
          const imageBlob = imageFile.getBlob();

          const element = foundElement.getElement();
          const text = element.asText();

          // Replace placeholder by empty text
          text.replaceText(placeholder, " ");

          const container = text.getParent();
          const index = container.getChildIndex(text);

          const image = container.insertInlineImage(index, imageBlob);
          const imageWidth = placeholders[placeholder].width;
          const imageAspectRatio = image.getWidth() / image.getHeight();
          const imageHeight = imageWidth / imageAspectRatio;
          image.setWidth(imageWidth).setHeight(imageHeight);
      
          const paragraph = image.getParent();
          if (paragraph.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
            paragraph.setAlignment(placeholders[placeholder].horizontalAlignment);
          }
        }
         else {
         const element = foundElement.getElement();
          const text = element.asText();
          const newText = text.getText().replace(placeholder, "").trim();

        if (newText === "") {
          const paragraph = element.getParent();
          paragraph.removeFromParent();
        } else {
        text.replaceText(placeholder, "");
        }
        }
      }
    }`
```

And here the part for the placeholder:

```
   `  "{{P&I}}": {
        cell: "E234",
        width: 570,
        horizontalAlignment: DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER,
      },`
```

Comment: About `There is now one image which has to be rotated when it is replacing a placeholder.`, how many degrees do you want to rotate? Unfortunately, from your question and showing script, I couldn't understand it. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for your reply. I have about 50 placeholder which are replaced by images. But one image has to be rotated by 90°CCW. It is a image which is normaly printed on A3 landscape but when i want to insert it in the doc, it has to be portrait.

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Thank you for replying.  Can I ask you about the detail of `rotated by 90°CCW`? And, about `But one image has to be rotated by 90°CCW`, how can I see it? Unfortunately, from your showing script, I couldn't understand it. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, "rotated by 90°CCW" means that the image is normaly landscape. But to insert it in my document it has to be rotated 90 degree counter clock wise. Each image has a placeholder. The placeholder for this specific image is {{P&I}}. In the variables it is defined where the image-id could be found. In this case in cell E234. The widht specifies the size of the image and the horizontalAligment specifies where the picture is placed in the document. I need now a kind of additional variable, for example "rotate: 90" in the variables.